# Django generic views problems with url

Tags: django

I'm creating a website which has two list views and a details view. I have no problem getting from the first listview to the second, but I'm unsure of how to make the url for the details view

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ItemsView.as_view(), name='items'),

url(r'^(?P<category_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<products_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='details'),


]
```

im not sure what to replace "category_id" and "products_id" with on the bottom url

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from .models import Category, Products


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'products/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_categories'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Category.objects.all()


class ItemsView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'products/items.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_items'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Products.objects.all()


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Products
    template_name = 'products/details.html'
```

html:

```
{% extends 'products/base.html' %}

{%block title%}Home{%endblock%}

{% block body %}
{% if all_items %}
    <ul>
        {% for product in all_items  %}
        <li><a href="{?????????}">{{product.name}}</a>  </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <h3>You have no categories</h3>
{% endif %}

{%  endblock %}
```

also what would go in the url here where the question marks are

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use name of your url, define in your url.py.
[Check the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls)

```
<li><a href="{% url 'details' product.pk %}">{{ product.name }}</a></li>
```

Why do you need category in your url ?? You can access to your product like this. And your DetailView need only the primary key of the object.

```
url(r'^product/(?P<products_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='details'),
```

Comment: i get a NoReverseMatch at error, what should the url be in the urls file?

Comment: because for items i just pk, but that doesnt work on details for some reason

Comment: Yes, you need to rewrite your url. You just need pk of product. No need category pk.

Comment: i tried that and it gives me the url /products/products/1, when i need something like products/1/1/ the first 1 being the category id

Comment: nevermind i changed it to
      url(r'^product/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='details'),
and it worked thanks

Comment: Why do you need Caterogy id to display details about Product ?

Comment: Yes, the string between < > is just the name of parameter in request.GET